# GROUP BY and COUNTs not producing expected results

Tags: sql, group-by

I am doing some SQL exercises, but I'm stuck in the one I'll describe.

There is a table called product that has 3 columns: maker, model and type.

This is the result of `select * from product`

[image]

The excercise says this:
Find out makers who produce only the models of the same type, and the number of those models exceeds 1.
Deduce: maker, type.

The correct query should return this:

[image]

My approach was to first see which makers made only one type of product and then exclude those makers who have only one model. To do that I used the following query, and it returns the correct result, except for the fact that I can only manage to display the maker, but not the type and the exercise asks for both.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT maker
FROM product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1 
AND
COUNT(model)> 1
```

And it returns this:

[image]

then, when I try to display the type as well by doing this:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT maker,type
FROM product
GROUP BY maker,type
HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1 
AND
COUNT(model)> 1
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Do you have any idea of why this is not working as expected? What would you do to solve this problem? I've been trying to solve this for over 3 hours with no success. :( Help me please.

Comment: which number of exercise is that?

Comment: Bonus Tip: You should never use DISTINCT and GROUP BY together in the same SELECT level.  It should never be necessary (DISTINCT is actually just a simplified/reduced form of GROUP BY), but it is often confusing and has the potential for unexpected and inconsistent results. (I don't think that this is the problem here though.)

Comment: oh, i have not completed that yet, so i will just close my eyes and stop understanding answers

Comment: @llamerr I've done all from 1 to 25, but I skipped 14 because I had worked on it for almost two hours and then came back haha.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are only returning those groups containing exactly one type you can just use `MAX`/`MIN` to find out what the `type` in that group is.

```
SELECT maker,
       MAX(type) AS type
FROM   product
GROUP  BY maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1
       AND COUNT(model) > 1
```

When you add `type` into the `GROUP BY` list it will give you a result row for every combination of `maker,type` which is why your second attempt doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work just like that, I just removed the type from group type and it did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How does it work that MAX was applied to a column containing values like "PC" "Laptop" "Printer". Those are not numerical values. What did it calculate the MAX of?

Comment: @user734063 It returns the value that would be sorted last.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker, type 
FROM product 
WHERE maker IN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT maker 
    FROM product 
    GROUP BY maker HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1
    AND count(model) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
DISTINCT maker, type
FROM makertype
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1 
AND
COUNT(ident)> 1
```

You're trying to group by maker and type in the second query, which will isolate any combination of maker and type that has exactly one type (which will always be true, since each group contains one distinct pair of maker and type) and two or more models.  You only want to group by maker.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct product.maker, product.type from product, (SELECT maker

    FROM product

    GROUP BY maker

    HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1 

           AND

           COUNT(model)> 1) as x

    where x.maker=product.maker
```

Try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAKER,MAX(TYPE)
 FROM PRODUCT
 GROUP  BY MAKER
 HAVING  COUNT(*)>1  AND  MAX(TYPE)=MIN(TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select maker, max(type) as type from Product
Group by maker
Having count (Distinct type) = 1 and Count(maker)>1
```